# In Luke 18: Pharisee and Tax Collector

Tags: luke, temple, prayer, tithes

In Luke 18, we read the story of the prayers of the Pharisee and the Tax Collector in the temple. The Pharisee's prayer (vv 11-12):

> The Pharisee, standing by himself, prayed thus: ‘God, I thank you that I am not like other men, extortioners, unjust, adulterers, or even like this tax collector. I fast twice a week; I give tithes of all that I get.<sub>([ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/Luke%2018%3A10-12/))</sub>

It seems like he is making a self-assessment rather than offering prayer to God. Is this prayer in a pattern typical of a formulaic type of prayer practiced among the Pharisees? Do we know anything more about the structure of typical prayers in the liturgy of the Second Temple period?

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange!
Be sure to visit the [tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about this site. You may want to see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Hello, Rich, and welcome. Your question seemed to me opinion-based, which can be a reason for closure on this site. I have re-written it to try to make it about the historical context of a particular text instead. Please take a look and see if it remains consistent with your intentions. You can roll back anything you don't like.

Answer (score 1):

The Jews today (some, actually) pray something along the lines of "Thank God I'm a Jew and not a Gentile. Thank you God, you've made me a man and not a [woman/slave](http://www.myjewishlearning.com/texts/Liturgy_and_Prayers/Siddur_Prayer_Book/Morning_blessings/three-blessings.shtml)".

Appearently this prayer links to the 3rd century BCE. It's not an uncommon prayer structure, and it's structure was criticized by the RaMBaM

> There were also internal, Jewish critics of the dawn blessings who were troubled not by any anti-Gentile content but by the danger of the **formulas' becoming so ritualized** as to be detached from lived experience. Two such critics were Maimonides and his son, the Judeo-Sufi pietist Abraham Maimuni. They were joined by the Franco-German pietists known as Hasidei Ashkenaz, whose richly mythic worldview otherwise differed greatly from Maimonides' rationalism.

Comment: Could you expand that citation so that others can find it? We like [sources to be cited well](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/1055/423). Also, this doesn't fully answer the question. It's more of a comment on it needing further explanation and research.

Answer (score -1):

**Do we know anything more about the structure of typical prayers in the liturgy of the Second Temple period?**

I am not so sure the word "liturgy" would be appropriate.

We do have a record that there was public prayer as almost a performance similar to what is recorded in Luke 18.

> Matthew 6:5  And when thou prayest, thou shalt not be as the
>   hypocrites are: for they love to pray standing in the synagogues and
>   in the corners of the streets, that they may be seen of men. Verily I
>   say unto you, They have their reward.

Comment: Could you elaborate any more? You haven't presented any historical evidence that would indicate Matthew is talking about a prayer in this format from Luke - it is purely speculative. Extrabiblical historical sources would greatly strengthen your argument.